# Can you remove steps in a gauge?

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-charting, aggregateresult, gaugeseries

I built a custom vf gauge chart, which looked and worked well in the sandbox. When we had it look against real data the chart gets ugly. The values are too high to show with any meaning.

[image: Dashboard]

I created two metrix dashboard components to show the max amount (Goal in picture) and needle amount (actual in picture).

Is there a way to hide all the steps values? Or can I round them into millions or thousands? Or only show the max value?

VF Component:

```
<apex:page controller="ISOGaugeControllerExecYTD">
<apex:chart height="180" width="400" animate="true" data="{!data}" legend="false">
    <apex:axis type="Gauge" position="top" title="Sum of Amount in USD" minimum="0" maximum="{!max1}" margin="-9"/>          
    <apex:gaugeSeries dataField="size" donut="50"/>
</apex:chart>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class ISOGaugeControllerExecYTD {
public Integer getMax1() {
    AggregateResult max =   [select sum(Goal__c) goal 
                            FROM ISO_Goal__c 
                            Where Goal__c != null 
                            AND Goal_Date__c = THIS_FISCAL_YEAR
                            AND RecordType.Name = 'Individual Goal'];

    Integer max1 = Integer.valueOf(max.get('goal'));
    return max1;
    }
public List<gaugeData> getData() {

    AggregateResult Actuals =   [select sum(amount__c) sum 
                                FROM Actuals__c 
                                Where Amount__c != null 
                                AND Actual_Date__c = THIS_FISCAL_YEAR
                                AND ISO_Goal__r.RecordType.Name = 'Individual Goal'];

    List<gaugeData> data = new List<gaugeData>();
    data.add(new gaugeData('Actual', Integer.valueof(actuals.get('sum'))));
    return data;
}
// Wrapper class
public class gaugeData {

public String name { get; set; }
public Integer size { get; set; }

public gaugeData(String name, Integer data) {
    this.name = name;
    this.size = data;
    }
  }   
}
```

Comment: You should just manipulate the values in `Apex` to reflect 1M increments instead. Probably should make sure you only display one decimal place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anywhere you are using:

```
Integer.valueOf(someAggregate.get('sum'));
```

Instead use:

```
(Integer)((Decimal)someAggregate.get('sum')).divide(1000000, 0);
```

You can break it out into more lines for readability.

```
Decimal aggregateValue = (Decimal)someAggregate.get('sum');
Integer displayValue = (Integer)aggregateValue.divide(1000000, 0);
```

**Don't forget to change your title attribute to reflect these changes.**

```
<apex:axis ... title="Sum of Amount in 1M USD" />
```

Comment: This is good stuff. I think I would have to create some if statements if it's over 1 million to divide by 1,000,000 else if it's in the thousands divide by 100,000.

Of course then I have to make the title a variable to display which value it divided by...

Comment: @DanWooding Right, you could certainly make the divisor more dynamic, if you're worried about scalability. I think it'll be simpler to just find one value that works, but you would follow a similar approach either way.